# Xml Parsing is not working-it returns nothing

Tags: python

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSPY v2004 rel. 2 U (http://www.xmlspy.com) by Alex Mantzaris (Firaxis Games) -->
<!-- Sid Meier's Civilization 4 -->
<!-- Copyright Firaxis Games 2005 -->
<!-- -->
<!-- Leader Infos and AI Settings -->
<Civ4LeaderHeadInfos xmlns="x-schema:CIV4CivilizationsSchema.xml">
    <LeaderHeadInfos>
        <LeaderHeadInfo>
            <Type>LEADER_BARBARIAN</Type>
            (............)
    </LeaderHeadInfo>
    <LeaderHeadInfo>
            (.....etc....)
```

This is XML file. and

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, dump, ElementTree

try:
    tree = ET.parse('CIV4LeaderHeadInfos.xml')
except:
    try:
        xm=input('Directory: ')
    except:
        print("Error: typed wrong directory.")
        quit()
    tree = ET.parse(xm)

root = tree.getroot()
##print(root)
ltag = root.findall("LeaderHeadInfo")
print(ltag)
print(ltag[0].find("Type").text)
```

This is the code I made.

```
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aaaa5\Desktop\Study\Python\LeaderXML.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(ltag[0].find("Type").text)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is what i got when i ran the program.
ltag is supposed to return but it does not.
What should I do to make it properly work?

Comment: Your xml is invalid - it opens tags, but never closes them (except for `Type`)

Comment: Sorry to confuse you Grismar, It is valid xml but I didn't include rest of them cause the file is way too long.

Comment: Most of your code only deals with somehow trying to open and parse a "directory" if parsing the file throws an error. Ignoring that and given that `LeaderHeadInfos` is actually in the document, your code works, until `print(ltag[0].find())`, as `.find()` expects a path.

Comment: Sorry again, I uploaded wrong code. It looks like findall() does not work as intended since it returns blank list.

Comment: This is the result when i run the program:                                                            
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aaaa5\Desktop\Study\Python\LeaderXML.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(ltag[0].find("Type").text)
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the full traceback, properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

**There are different things going on**:

1. `Element.findall()` finds only elements with a tag which are direct children of the current element. And `LeaderHeadInfo` are not direct children of `root`
2. It seems that the namespace cause the trouble, so you may check the [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces)

**The following is an example how it would work(notice, deleted namespace)**

```
content='''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Civ4LeaderHeadInfos>
<LeaderHeadInfos>
    <LeaderHeadInfo>
    <Type>LEADER_BARBARIAN</Type>
    </LeaderHeadInfo>
    <LeaderHeadInfo>
    <Type>LEADER_HedgeHog</Type>
    </LeaderHeadInfo>
    <LeaderHeadInfo>
    <Type>LEADER_WhatEver</Type>
    </LeaderHeadInfo>
</LeaderHeadInfos>
</Civ4LeaderHeadInfos>
        
'''
        
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree, fromstring

tree = ElementTree(fromstring(content))
#tree = ET.fromstring(content)

root = tree.getroot()

for ltag in root.findall('.//LeaderHeadInfo/Type'):
     print(ltag.text)
```

**Output**

```
LEADER_BARBARIAN
LEADER_HedgeHog
LEADER_WhatEver
```

Comment: Thank you HedgeHog! Did not know there was official document about it. I think it'll help me much.

Comment: @Gamjago: Check the answer of Alexandra Dudkina, it handles the namespace part great

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces should be considered when parsing XML:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

namespaces = {'ns': 'x-schema:CIV4CivilizationsSchema.xml'}

leader_head_infos = root.findall('ns:LeaderHeadInfos', namespaces)[0]
leader_head_info_list = leader_head_infos.findall("ns:LeaderHeadInfo", namespaces)
print(leader_head_info_list)
print(leader_head_info_list[0].find("ns:Type", namespaces).text)
```

Comment: Didn't know about namespaces.(complete noob :P) Thank you, Dudkina! Helps me a lot!